# FOSElasticaBundle: Setting analyzer for custom properties

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, elastica, foselasticabundle

I am using the FOSElasticaBundle in Symfony 3.3. I have registered an event listener on the POST_TRANSFORM event that computes and [adds a custom property](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/cookbook/custom-properties.md) like this:

```
public function addCustomProperty(TransformEvent $event)
{
    $document = $event->getDocument();
    $custom = $this->anotherService->calculateCustom($event->getObject());

    $document->set('custom', $custom);
}
```

Now I need to set the analyzer to be used for this property. How can I do that?

I already tried to add the custom field name to the type definition in my fos_elastica config but that causes an exception as the bundle then expects that property on my entity as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out that I could use `dynamic_templates` to set the desired analyzer like this:

```
fos_elastica:
  indexes:
    app:
      types:
        myentity:
          dynamic_templates:
            custom_field:
              path_match: customfield.*
              mapping:
                analyzer: myanalyzer
          properties:
            ...
```